# no module called vtkParallelPython error in Paraview python

Tags: vtk, paraview, pvpython

I tried to run example PythonFullExample from https://github.com/acbauer/CatalystExampleCode 
I have installed paraview, vtk and mpi. Why do I get  no module called vtkParallelPython error.
I'm using ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you need to run this Python example with a build directory of ParaView instead of an install directory.